# Is there any way to keep current page when sorting jqgrid columns?

Tags: jqgrid

My jqgrid contains several pages. When I sort any column the page resets to first.

(That's right also for filterToolbar i.e. after calling $("#my-grid")[0].triggerToolbar();)

Is there any way to keep my current page after sorting/filtering ?

**EDIT:**

Actually my problem is a little more complicated.

I save jqgrid preferences(rowNum, page, filters etc..) to the cookie.
When I load the page first time I load the prefs. 
I use the technique from Mark B's answer (see [jqGrid Filter Toolbar initial default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440417/jqgrid-filter-toolbar-initial-default-value)) to populate my filter default values.

The problem: in that case page always sets to the first.(because of triggerToolbar calling) i.e. it doesn't save state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your requirement. If the user has seen some rows on the second page for example and then the user has clicked on the column header to sort the column the the grid will be sorted. The data which the user have seen before can be on any page. So I don't understand why you want hold the current page which will show absolutely another data as it showed before.

If you do need to hold the page you can do this in the following way. Inside of the `loadComplete` you can save the value of `page` parameter. Inside of `onSortCol` event handler the value will be already changed to 1, but you can correct it to the value which you saved before. I didn't tested this, but I think it should work.

**UPDATED:** Now I think I understand your original problem. I think you should choose another way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023942/jqgrid-first-load-filtering/6024253#6024253) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching/4509018#4509018). What you needs is just to save in the cookie the `postData` value and to set `search:true` parameter of jqGrid if the `filters` is not empty (or other filter parameter depend on the options which you use). In the way you should be able to restore not only the filter, but additionally the `page` value. The final solution can a little depend from jqGrid parameters and the parameters of `filterToolbar` which you use. So it you will have implementation problem you should include more code which you use.

Comment: I checked, it works. Thanks! 
You are probably right about the behavior. It doesn't make a lot of sense it this cases.
I asked the question(more abstract) because I though it help me with my actual problem.

Comment: @mt_serg: You are welcome! I wrote "Updated" part in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advices!
I solve the problem by adding new "overridePage" value to "postData" when jqgrid loads first time.
Instead of calling $("#my-grid")[0].triggerToolbar() I call the following func:


function triggerToolbar(gridId, newPage) {
        var postData = $("#" + gridId).getGridParam('postData');
        postData.overridePage = newPage;
        $("#"+gridId)[0].triggerToolbar();
        delete postData.overridePage;
}


On the server side I check 'overridePage' value and if it exists just used it. p.s. sorry for formatting

Comment: @mt_serg: You are welcome! I am glad to hear/read that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mvc with jqgrid and this solition work for me:

```
$("#GridTable").jqGrid({
...
onSortCol:
            function () {

                var postpage = jQuery("#GridTable").getGridParam('postData');
                jQuery("#GridTable").setGridParam({ page: postpage.page });
           },
...
});
```