# jqGrid filter upon display

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have seen lots of questions and answer about this.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to have a grid filtered when I first display it.  I have a filter toolbar, and can successfully filter after it is loaded from user input data.  The problem is when trying to filter prior to user input.

```
grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
       { name: 'someName', label: 'someLabel', index: 'someIndex', width: 110,
         sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", 
         searchoptions: { defaultValue:'Default value' } }
    ...

grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn', stringResult: true });
```

the column filter is successfully set to "Default Value".   I can go press enter on it, and have the column filtered by it.  What can I do to have the grid initialize itself with the filter set?

I know that I can call

```
grid[0].triggerToolbar();
```

To have the postdata.filters updated.  But, if I do that after setting the toolbar above, it is too late.  The query has already been sent to the server.  I am sure that I need to do this perhaps in beforeSend?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here works: [jqGrid Filter Toolbar initial default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440417/jqgrid-filter-toolbar-initial-default-value)

Is this the best / only way?

Scott